# Custom themes for Coda like there are TextMate

Tags: coda

Is there custom themes for CODA? as in preferences there is a export and import button. So i am guessing yes? But i am unable to locate any on the internet

Answer (score 1):

I've created several: http://joebergantine.com/werkstatt/seestyle. If you search around the archives of the coda users group there's several listed there. I suggest the phrase "seestyle theme".

Comment: Yes thanks...i am using this now. i like it a lot, nice and easy on the eyes

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: http://ipaintcode.com/coda-2-themes/ 
Also forkable on github: https://github.com/ipaintcode/Coda-2-Themes